# How to use JsonConvert.SerializeObject with formatting to add brackets only around CSV values

Tags: json.net

I have an object that, when converted to a JSON string using the `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` method, will look like this:

```
{"01":{"CompanyName":"Hertz","Cars":"Ford, BMW, Fiat"},
 "02":{"CompanyName":"Avis","Cars":"Dodge, Nash, Buick"}}
```

How can I use the `Formatting` parameter to make the result look like this:

```
{"01":{"CompanyName":"Hertz","Cars":["Ford", "BMW", "Fiat"]},
 "02":{"CompanyName":"Avis","Cars":["Dodge", "Nash", "Buick"]}}
```

Comment: Can you share the class that corresponds to this?

Comment: The second JSON sample is semantically different from the first -- the `"Cars"` property value has been changed from a string to an array value.  You can't use the [`Formatting` enumeration](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Formatting.htm) to make this change since formatting simply *Causes child objects to be indented according to the Indentation and IndentChar settings* which is cosmetic not semantic.  Can you share your existing classes and serialization code?  The required output can certainly be generated using a different approach.

Comment: Yep. it should be "Cars" all the way.  So, I will add the brackets in the business logic when I assign the CSV value to that particular property of the object.

Comment: In your desired output, you have it as `["Ford, BMW, Fiat"]` which represents an array containing a single CSV string value.  Is that what you really want?  Usually in JSON you want `["Ford", "BMW", "Fiat"]` which represents an array containing three separate string values.

Comment: Brian, you are correct. The strings are separate.  By bad.  I have edited my question according to your comment and dbc's comment.  Nevertheless, I am still having to manually add the square brackets with the strings manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @dbc mentioned in the comments, you cannot use the `Formatting` parameter of `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` to affect whether a particular value in the JSON is surrounded by square brackets or not.  The `Formatting` parameter only controls whether or not Json.Net will add indenting and line breaks to the JSON output to make it easier to read by a human.

In JSON, square brackets are used to denote an *array* of values, as opposed to a single value.  So, if you want to add square brackets for a particular property, the easiest way to do that is to change how that property is declared in your class such that it correspondingly represents an array (or list).

Based on your original JSON, I'm assuming you have a class which looks like this:

```
public class Company
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string Cars { get; set; }
}
```

...and you are creating your JSON something like this:

```
var results = new Dictionary<string, Company>();

results.Add("01", new Company
{
    CompanyName = "Hertz",
    Cars = "Ford, BMW, Fiat"
});

results.Add("02", new Company
{
    CompanyName = "Avis",
    Cars = "Dodge, Nash, Buick"
});

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results);
```

To get square brackets in the JSON, change the type of your `Cars` property from `string` to `List<string>`:

```
public class Company
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public List<string> Cars { get; set; }
}
```

Of course, you will also need to make a corresponding change to the code which populates the results:

```
var results = new Dictionary<string, Company>();

results.Add("01", new Company
{
    CompanyName = "Hertz",
    Cars = new List<string> { "Ford", "BMW", "Fiat" }
});

results.Add("02", new Company
{
    CompanyName = "Avis",
    Cars = new List<string> { "Dodge", "Nash", "Buick" }
});

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results);
```

Here is a short demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/lgg9jk

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks for your help, Brian.